# How to sum different criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data that looks like this in Redshift:

```
+-------------+------------+---------+
| Employee_ID | Manager_ID | Revenue |
+-------------+------------+---------+
|         123 |        123 | 1015.24 |
|         541 |        123 | 5587.23 |
+-------------+------------+---------+
```

I want to write a query that sums manager revenue whenever a Manager_ID is inputted and sums employee revenue whenever an Employee_ID is inputted. Currently, I have a query that looks like this and I have to run it twice:

```
SELECT      
  sum(revenue) as revenue
FROM 
  employee_rev r
WHERE
  r.manager_id in ('123','124') --I change this to employee_ID the second time around
```

If it helps, there is another table like this:

```
+-------------+------------------------+
| Employee_ID |          Role          |
+-------------+------------------------+
|         123 | Manager                |
|         541 | Individual Contributor |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

Thank you so much for your time, this seemed really simple and now I'm pretty frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
SELECT sum(revenue) as revenue
FROM employee_rev r
WHERE 123 in (r.employee_id, r.manager_id);
```

That is, for a given id, look in both columns.  An employee should never be in the manager column, so this would appear to do what you want.

EDIT:

For multiple ids, you would have to test independently.  Either:

```
WHERE 123 IN (r.employee_id, r.manager_id) OR
      456 IN (r.employee_id, r.manager_id)
```

or:

```
WHERE r.employee_id in (123, 456) OR
      r.manager_id in (123, 456)
```

Comment: A manager has their own sales associated to them as an employee as in the first example in the table above. Would this double count that managers revenue?

Comment: @Crackers . . . It depends what you mean by "double count".  Any given row in the original table is counted only once, even the first row in your example.

Comment: Thank you, how would I modify what you have provided to include multiple ID's?

Comment: For example: WHERE (123,456) in (r.employee_id, r.manager_id);

Answer (score 0):

Use union to add two selects into one 'table', then sum it. I think this should work

```
SELECT sum(result) from (
    SELECT      
       sum(revenue) as result
    FROM 
       employee_rev r
    WHERE
       r.manager_id in ('123')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      
        sum(revenue) as result
    FROM 
        employee_rev r
    WHERE
        r.employee_id in ('124')
```

)

Comment: This would assume I know which is a manager and which is an employee, which unfortunately I don't unless I run a query. Is there another way to do this with a union in which the complete set is used? Thank you for your response!

Comment: i dont think so. Maybe your database has a bit bad structure for task. Why you cannot use this solution?